# How to show an external domain as a subfolder with ProxyPass and Varnish

Tags: apache, varnish, vhosts, proxypass

I have configured a vhost to show an external domain as a subdir:

```
<VirtualHost *>
ServerName example.com
DocumentRoot /home/www/example.com
...
<Location /subfolder/>
      ProxyPass http://www.externaldomain.com/
      SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
      SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
      Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
</Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

If I try to visit example.com/subfolder on stage server it works and I see externaldomain.com content.
If I try the same on production server I get a 500 error due to a Varnish problem.

This is my Varnish configuration:

```
backend default {
.host = "127.0.0.1";
.port = "8080";
}
```

and this is what is written in apache error log

```
[Tue Nov 19 16:33:51 2013] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /subfolder/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Can you suggest me how to solve?

I suppose I have to do something related to VCL but that's all.

Comment: Could you post your VCL and some debugging data (for example varnishlog output) as well?

Comment: @Ketola I have updated my post with what was written in apache error log. My /etc/varnish/default.vcl is very simple, it's completely reported at the bottom of the post.

Comment: @ketola looking at apache error log helped to solve my problem. I have installed missed modules with:a2enmod proxy proxy_balancer proxy_connect proxy_ftp proxy_http. Thanks

Comment: Good to hear you got it sorted out.